# Android/Java using two dimensional array to create chatbot

Tags: java, android, chatbot

```
public class ChatBot {
String[][] chatBot={
        // standard greetings
        { "hi", "hello", "hey" }, { "hi user"},
        // question greetings
        { "how are you" }, { "good"},
        // default
        { "I did not understand. Please try something else" }, };

public ChatBot() {
}

public String checkAnswer(String message) {
    byte response = 0;
    int messageType = 0;
    String x = null;
    List temp;
    int cblength = chatBot.length - 1;
    while (response == 0 && messageType <= cblength) {
        temp = Arrays.asList(chatBot[messageType]);
        if (temp.contains(message)) {
            response = 2;
            x = chatBot[(messageType) + 1][0];
        }

        messageType = messageType + 2;

        if (response == 1) 
            x = chatBot[chatBot.length - 1][0];
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

I created this simple chatbot to test my chat application. It uses  a two dimensional String Array to save the possible inputs and outputs. The checkAnwer method receives the user input and is supposed to return the correct output. It uses a while loop to check the input fields and return the corresponding output, if the content of the field matches with the array. If the loop reaches the end of the array, it is supposed to return the default answer.  The first group of inputs (hi/hello/hey) returns the right output(hi user), but every other input causes the while-loop to exceed the array length.

*Edit*

I removed the error in the Code, all inputs are now accepted, non valid inputs return null.

*Edit2*

I changed `int cblength = chatBot.length - 1;`
 
to 
`int cblength = chatBot.length;`

and `messageType = messageType + 2;`
 to

```
    if ((messageType+2)>=cblength)
    {
        response=1;
    }
    else {
        messageType = messageType + 2;
    }
```

The code is now working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, chatBot has a length of 5. On each full pass of the while loop, messageType is incrementing by 2. This means that on the second pass, messageType = 2. This means that on the following line :

```
 x = chatBot[(messageType * 2) + 1][0];
```

We are looking for (2*2)+1 = 5 as an index. As the list is of length 5, the max index is 4, causing the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

There are two main ways I could see to fix this:

1. Reconsider whether you really need to repeat the same block of code twice in the while loop - this adds a bit of unneeded complexity, and reduces how often the while conditions are checked.
2. Update the while condition to check that any (messageType*2)+1 which *will* occur during the iteration will still be within the bounds of the array.